# What is the term for shrinking the HTML code of websites? Came across some days ago, but unable to recollect now

Tags: coding-style

During browsing, I tried to view the source of a web page. The code was only of 4-5 lines but each line was of a long width. I understood that the code has been shrunk, but there was a strange word was used for it.

It was like *Bla Bla Bla* done by *SomeWebsite*

I am unable to recollect the word. Even I searched for it but forgot to bookmark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term is [minification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29).

Typically JavaScript and CSS are minified.

A good minifier will not only remove unnecessary symbols (e.g. white space and comments) but will also rewrite verbose JavaScript into an equivalent, more compact form.  Variable renaming is common for JavaScript minification.  An example of a more compact but equivalent expression is to use !0 for true and !1 for false.

One can also gain some efficiency by removing extra white space from HTML, though I have not personally heard that referred to as minifying.

Comment: Exactly!! This is it! Thanks. I even searched wiki that day for it. Thanks again.

Comment: Note that, if your web server has compression enabled (most do), HTML minification doesn't actually make a significant difference.

Comment: @duskwuff: The client also has to support it (most do of course).  I have seen research that ways HTML minification improves things 2%-5% above GZip depending on the source.  Not much, but it may make a difference especially if you can do it as a "compile" or "publish" step and not at runtime (where the CPU cost and time spent is not worth the gain).